# javascript dependencies in python project

Tags: javascript, python, dependency-management

I'm writing software that allows one to publish mathematical books as websites. It is based mostly on Python + Flask, but to deal with equations I'm using MathJax. MathJax can be used either client-side or server-side (through [MathJax-node](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node)). In the latter case I have to use `npm` to install MathJax-node in some place accessible to my main Python script, then invoke it from the script. In the former case, I have to provide MathJax.js as an asset, available to client (currently I use Flask's `send_from_directory` function).

My question is: what is the best practice of dealing with such heterogenous dependencies in Python? My goal is to make installation process as simple as possible at least on unix-like systems (Linux or MacOS), provided that `node` and `npm` are already available.

I can just put all the javascript sources I need into my distribution itself, but maybe there's a better way to do it?

Comment: softwareengineering.stackexchange.com might be a better fit for this question

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Good to know. I was not aware of that. Would migrating be considered appropriate in this case?

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger, thanks, I didn't know about that site. How can I migrate my question there? It seems that *close → offtopic → this question belongs to another SE site" gives me some sites but not *softwareengineering* as possible migration targets.

Comment: I have created and released the [calmjs](https://github.com/calmjs/calmjs) project for this specific use case, provided that `node` and `npm` are available, the integration packages (such as [`calmjs.webpack`](https://github.com/calmjs/calmjs.webpack)) should work.  At the very least, with calmjs it is possible to declare a `package.json` that is persisted as part of a given Python package as its metadata for reuse by their dependants.

Answer (score 7):

> My question is: what is the best practice of dealing with such
>   heterogenous dependencies in Python?

In the case of Node dependencies, I would include a `package.json` file in the directory which specifies the Node dependencies needed. For other languages/package managers, I would also use whatever the conventional way of specifying dependencies is (e.g. add a Gemfile for Ruby dependencies).

Another common example of this that comes up with Python/Flask is using the [Bower](https://bower.io/) package manager for static frontend dependencies. In that case, the dependencies are specified in the `bower.json` file and are usually pulled into a bower folder in Flask's `static` directory.

> I can just put all the javascript sources I need into my distribution
>   itself, but maybe there's a better way to do it?

Once you've got the `package.json` with the dependencies specified, you can fetch and install all the Node dependencies needed by running `npm install` which, in my opinion, is a more elegant solution than including the javascript sources with the project.

Now that you've got multiple package managers (e.g. maybe you're using `pip` for the Python dependencies in addition to `npm` for the Node dependencies), you might want to make a Makefile or some deployment/build script to fetch/install using all of them (for example, if I were using Travis CI, I would update my `.travis.yml` to call `npm install` in addition to `pip install -r`).

Comment: Thanks! A couple of questions: 1. If I'm using `npm install` to install necessary node packages (like MathJax-node), how it is possible to make Python script aware of the location of installed packages? 2. Am I right that it is impossible to deal with this node dependencies if I want my package to be installable with only `pip install <my-package-name>`? (I.e. it is impossible to invoke `npm install` from `setup.py`?)

Answer (score 3):

Using Node.js package.json would be the most optimal solution for dealing with JavaScript dependencies. As for executing executables from .py you can reference to this answer [Running shell command from Python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output#answer-4760517). Node dependencies are by default inside ./node_modules in the same directory as the location of your package.json file.

For installing new dependencies:

```
npm install --save npm-package-you-want-to-install
```

Once you have them prepared this command will have everything installed for you:

```
npm install
```

Node dependencies are definitely more elegant way of dealing with things since javascript is a constantly evolving world and it is much easier to take a look at a package.json than a lot of script tags / functions that simply invoke said scripts. If you want a automated system my suggestion would be to make a executable (.sh) which will run installment for both and you can use that in your future projects.

Comment: Thanks! A couple of questions: 1. If I'm using `npm install` to install necessary node packages (like MathJax-node), how it is possible to make Python script aware of the location of installed packages? 2. Am I right that it is impossible to deal with this node dependencies if I want my package to be installable with only `pip install <my-package-name>`? (I.e. it is impossible to invoke `npm install` from `setup.py`?)

Comment: node_modules are usually in the same folder as package.json. So in the case package.json is in root of your project, node_modules would be as well.
For py scripts (npm install) there's a link in the comment above.

Comment: Yeah, I understand how to invoke `npm install` from python. What I am asking for is the following. `setup.py` is basically an invokation of `setuptools.setup` function that will automatically find the correct place to install package. However, I cannot execute (at least don't know how to) execute arbitrary python commands (like `subprocess.run(["npm", "install"])` in the directory where my scripts are putted by `setuptools.setup`. This is why I cannot understand how my Python scripts (after they are installed) can be aware of the location of JavaScript dependancies.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use webpack [Webpack.js](https://webpack.js.org/) not Bowerjs. NPM and his package.json are very good for dependency updates but referencing libraries from node_modules is a little embarrasing.